# How can I change a visual studio code that creates a thematic map using equal ranges method, into creating thematic map using Natural breaks?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mapinfo, equal-range, map-basic

I am trying to use visual studio to create a thematic map that reads the
data in my Mapinfo table " Neighborhoods" and show them in a map by dividing the
data into equal ranges, and to do that I am using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MapInfo;


namespace Spatial_Analysis_On_Housing_Prices_Ankara
{
    public partial class Ankara_Neighborhood_Thematic : Form
    {

        public Ankara_Neighborhood_Thematic()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void removetematik()
        {
            for (int k = Convert.ToInt16(Form1.mi.Eval("mapperinfo(" + Form1.win_id + ",9)")); k > 0; k = k - 1)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt16(Form1.mi.Eval("layerinfo(" + Form1.win_id + "," + Convert.ToString(k) + ",24)")) == 3)
                {
                    Form1.mi.Do("remove map layer \"" + Form1.mi.Eval("layerinfo(" + Form1.win_id + "," + Convert.ToString(k) + ",1)") + "\"");
                }
            }
        }


        private void Ankara_Neighborhood_Thematic_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }


        private void thematic_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
            string p = panel1.Handle.ToString();
            string thematic_column = string.Empty;
            removetematik();



            thematic_column = listBox1.Text;

            

            Form1.mi.Do("select Max(" + thematic_column + ") from Neighbourhoods  into maxselect");
            Double maxx = Convert.ToDouble(Form1.mi.Eval("maxselect.col1"));
            Form1.mi.Do("select Min(" + thematic_column + ") from Neighbourhoods  into minselect");
            Double minn = Convert.ToDouble(Form1.mi.Eval("minselect.col1"));


            Form1.mi.Do("select " + thematic_column + " from Neighbourhoods order by " + thematic_column + " into sel noselect");

            int diff = Convert.ToInt32(maxx - minn);
            int range = diff / n;

            int c_range = Convert.ToInt16(255 / n);


            Form1.mi.Do("fetch first from sel");
            string r1 = Convert.ToString(Form1.mi.Eval("sel.col1"));
            string r2 = string.Empty;
            string cmstr = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {

                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(r1) + range;
                r2 = temp.ToString();

                
                string rgb = Convert.ToString(Form1.mi.Eval("RGB(255," + Convert.ToString((n - i) * c_range) + "," + Convert.ToString((n - i) * c_range) + ")"));
                cmstr = cmstr + r1 + ":" + r2 + " brush(2," + rgb + ",16777215), ";
                r1 = r2;

            }

            Form1.mi.Do("fetch last from sel");
            r2 = Convert.ToString(Form1.mi.Eval("sel.col1"));
            cmstr = cmstr + r1 + ":" + r2 + " brush(2,16711680,16777215)";

            Form1.mi.Do("shade window " + Form1.win_id + " Neighbourhoods with " + thematic_column + " ranges apply all use color Brush (2,16711680,16777215) " + cmstr);

            Form1.mi.Do("Set Next Document Parent " + p + " Style 1");
            Form1.mi.Do("Create Cartographic Legend From Window " + Form1.win_id + " Behind Frame From Layer 3");


        }


    }
}
```

Now I want to change the parts that uses equal ranges into "Natural breaks" instead, how can I do that?

I have a code for creating thematic map in natural breaks method but its in mapbasic format, I want it in C# taking into consideration the code for equal ranges as template.

this is the mapbasic code:

```
include "mapbasic.def"
dim rrr() as float, dolgu() as brush
dim k as integer
create ranges from Neighbourhoods with AvG_Price_Per_Sq_meter use "Natural Break" number 10 round 1000 into variable rrr

for k=1 to 20
print rrr(k)
next    

Create Styles 
    From Brush(2, white, 0) 'style for LOW range
    To Brush (2, RED, 0) 'style for HIGH range
    Vary Color By "RGB" 
    Number 10 
    Into Variable dolgu

shade Neighbourhoods
    With AvG_Price_Per_Sq_meter
    Ranges 
        From Variable rrr 
        Style Variable dolgu
```

I am trying to change the parts that creates thematic map from my data using equal ranges method into natural breaks method instead.

Comment: Try calculating it using the MapInfo command Create Ranges. The resulting ranges are then converted to C# arrays and used to generate thematic maps.